# Installing OWASP’s WebScarab

Tags: owasp, webscarab

I am following a book named "Web Security Testing Cookbook.pdf" (O'REILLY) by Paco Hope & Ben Walther. For installing standalone WebScarab I have found the following instruction:

To obtain the standalone version, browse to the WebScarab project at SourceForge:

```
http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=64424&package_id=61823
```

Once you’ve downloaded the standalone version, double-click the WebScarab .jar file.

After visiting http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=64424&package_id=61823 I found a file named "testing.sxw". As I didn't find any jar file what to do with testing.sxw?

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisite: jre1.4 or later

1. Download "webscarab-selfcontained-20070504-1631.jar" from http://sourceforge.net/projects/owasp/files/WebScarab/20070504-1631/
2. Run the jar file by double-click OR from command prompt by using the command:

   java -jar webscarab-selfcontained-20070504-1631.jar

WebScarab will be run successfully.

Comment: Thanks, everything goes well but I'm getting an error at the end of the installation as you mentioned.        
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x53167b16, pid=12148, tid=0x00004314
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\sajeev.sahadevan\hs_err_pid12148.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Answer (score 1):

It looks like testing.sxw is an OpenOffice file. See details here -  http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/SXW-OpenOffice-org-1-0-Text-Document.

I can open the file using TextEdit on my OSX. So you will need a viewer for .sxw file for the platform you are running on. Hope that helps.

Comment: According to instruction in the link above, I renamed the file as testing.doc. But unfortunately I failed to open with MS Word in Windows7 64-bit.

Comment: Maybe you want to install OpenOffice (http://www.openoffice.org/product/windows.html) and use that to open the file.

Comment: Yes, I can try to open the file by installing OpenOffice. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have downloaded "Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Win_x86_install_en-US.exe" and installed successfully in Windows7. I have opened the file testing.sxw by OpenOffice. The file contains many valuable information/topics, but no WebScarab installation guide.